# Why do I have to put BOOL in implementation (iOS)

Tags: ios, boolean, nsuserdefaults

In my header file I made BOOL RED;

I need to save a BOOL so the user clicks the BOOL once and never again. However, in implementation when in viewDidLoad when I placed the following code, NOTHING saved.

```
RED=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]boolForKey:@"save"];
```

When I placed the following code the BOOL saved...

```
BOOL RED=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]boolForKey:@"save"];
```

Why do I have to place BOOL RED in front of RED for saving to work? How do I save it without putting BOOL in front of RED? Is this wrong?

I don't understand why I'm getting voted down. Can I at least get an explanation with what's wrong?

EDIT:

```
-(IBAction)REDbutton:(id)sender{

item.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"REDthing.png"];

RED=YES;  //BOOL



}
```

Comment: You are getting down-voted because your question is very poorly written and lacks some formatting. And because it is not very clear what you are asking for. Something about saving without any code actually "saving" anything and something about booleans in .h and .m files....

Comment: Explaining is an art.!!

Comment: I stated that  I declared a BOOL RED in header file. Then in implementation file I had to again type in BOOL RED for "saving" to work. The "saving" wouldn't work if I had just typed RED  in implementation file and I was wondering why that was.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea how you determine that

```
BOOL RED=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]boolForKey:@"save"];
```

saves anything because this line of code is not supposed to save. It loads a value from the user defaults. If you want to save a BOOL into user defaults you need to do the following:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:RED forKey:@"save"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

and after you saved it this way you can read the value from the user defaults by the means of code adduced by you. And it doesn't matter at all how you read it: `RED =` or `BOOL RED =`

P.S. RED is not an appropriate name for a variable.

Comment: Well that code saves. Only while inside the app. It's not saved when you exit the app and open it up again.  the synchronize part isn't supposed to be used for iOS 8.

Comment: I have no idea what are you talking about

Comment: BOOL RED=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]boolForKey:@"save"]; I put that code in viewDidLoad. Nothing else. while in the app, the BOOL gets saved after 1 click. However, when I closed out of the app and opened back up again, the BOOL didn't save.

Comment: Sorry, buddy, really I can't understand you. Why do you put BOOL RED=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]boolForKey:@"save"]; for SAVING? It DOES NOT SAVE anything. It performs exactly antipodal operation. It READS from the user defaults

Comment: I tried different versions of NSUserDefaults StandardUserDefaults today including what you suggested, I tried as well. It didn't work. I read for iOS 8 using synchronize is unreliable.

Comment: You are doing something extremely simple. I'd do that in two minutes. The problem is that you can't explain what you need

Comment: I'm making a game. I need that when the user clicks on the button, it saves the RED Bool that's inside the button. It saves it so that the user never has to click on that button again. Even if they exit the app and come back into the app, that button is saved and when the game starts, they start playing as RED. This is what i'm looking for.

Comment: A BOOL inside the button??? Oh...))) If you send me your project I'll make it work

Comment: I edited in my my code for what's inside my button. What it states is when the user clicks on the button, the RED BOOL is now the character and the character is REDthing.png